# How can I get the records based on condition on date and time of created_time column of sample dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

sample dataframe(df) having following columns:

```
     id     created_time     faid                                            
0    21 2019-06-17 07:06:45  FF1854155    
1    54 2019-04-12 08:06:03  FF30232     
2    88 2019-04-20 05:36:03  FF1855531251     
3   154 2019-04-26 07:09:22  FF8145292   
4   218 2019-07-25 13:20:51  FF0143154   
5   219 2019-04-30 18:50:24  FF04211 
6   235 2019-04-30 20:37:37  FF0671380   
7   266 2019-05-02 08:38:56  FF08070   
8   268 2019-05-02 11:08:21  FF591087
```

How can i get the records whose created_time is between 2019-04-01 00:00:00 and 2019-06-30 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. convert datetime into datetime format using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
2. Apply simply less than greator than to fetch data between two dates

```
df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])

res = df[(df['created_time']>= '2019-04-01')&(df['created_time']<='2019-06-30')]
```

## Second Solution

by @anky_91

```
df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])
df[df.created_time.between('2019-04-01 00:00:00','2019-06-30 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: In case i have condition between some time to time ?

Comment: `df[df.created_time.between('2019-04-01 00:00:00','2019-06-30 00:00:00')]`

Comment: you just need to provide time like `df['created_time']> '2019-04-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: Does we have .notbetween case too ?

Comment: try this `df[~(df.created_time.between('2019-04-01 00:00:00','2019-06-30 00:00:00'))]`

Comment: @Codenewbie no problem kindly approve if you find it helpful

Comment: according to the documentation - [`pandas.DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), -  "you get the times that are not between two times by setting `start_time` later than `end_time`"

Comment: How may I achieve this, getting only hours from created_time and count of same hours---for eg: 08 -2,07-2, this result as another dataframe ....

Comment: @Codenewbie please post new question so that more people can view it and can contribute in it

Answer (score 1):

Simply as

```
df.loc[(df['created_time'] >= pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=4, day=1)) & (df['created_time'] <= pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=6, day=30))]
```

Comment: great answer but, I guess it is '<= 'after '&' in the answer

Comment: yup, it is. fixed :)

Comment: how can i apply the same in case if 'time' also is in?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), you can use further keywords: `pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=4, day=1, hour=13, minute=15, second=56, microsecond=965000)`

Answer (score -1):

You could parse the input to get the date as a string, convert it to a datetime object (if you want to use Python built-in) and then compare the parsed time to your min and max datetimes :

```
import datetime

time_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

dt_min=datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-04-01 00:00:00', time_format)
dt_max=datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-06-30 00:00:00', time_format)

content = open('file.txt', 'r').read()

for line in content.split('\n')[1:]:
  parsed=line.split()
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{parsed[2]} {parsed[3]}', time_format)

  if dt < dt_max and dt > dt_min:
    print('ok:', dt)
  else:
    print('nok', dt)
```

You can try this code here : https://repl.it/repls/TrustyPleasedMatch